# PHP - Modify absolute path/URL of images on a string text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to migrate old blog posts (based on WP) to a new platform. One of the steps is defined by:

1. Get full_text of posts
2. Search for the existence of full path/url of old images (let's set *https://stackoverflow.com/uploads/logo.png* or just *uploads/logo.png*)
3. Extract/save and get the guid() of new images
4. Switch old path *https://stackoverflow.com/uploads/logo.png* to a new one (let's see *https://quora.com/media/brand123.png*

**I tried a regex expression to search for old urls:**
`/(http:\/\/stackoverflow\.com\/uploads\/)+(.*?)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)/`

**And then tried:**

```
$old = array();
$pattern = "/(https:|http:\/\/stackoverflow\.com\/uploads\/)+(.*?)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)/";
$text = "orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <img src='https://stackoverflow.com/uploads/image1.png'/> rem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <img src='https://stackoverflow.com/uploads/image2.png'/>";

// seatch and get old urls
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $old);
```

But it get's me something like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(44) "https://stackoverflow.com/uploads/image1.png"
    [1]=>
    string(44) "https://stackoverflow.com/uploads/image2.png"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "https:"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "https:"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "//stackoverflow.com/uploads/"
    [1]=>
    string(28) "//stackoverflow.com/uploads/"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) ".png"
    [1]=>
    string(4) ".png"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this regex will do the job a bit better:

```
#\b((?:https?://stackoverflow\.com/)?uploads/(.*?\.(?:jpg|png|gif)))\b#
```

I've simplified a bit of yours (e.g. replace `https:|http:` with `https?:`) and also removed what seems like an unnecessary `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`. I've also improved the grouping, making some non-capturing:

The new code (note I added an extra image reference for testing):

```
$old = array();
$pattern = "#\b((?:https?://stackoverflow\.com/)?uploads/(.*?\.(?:jpg|png|gif)))\b#";
$text = "orem uploads/xyx.gif ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <img src='https://stackoverflow.com/uploads/image1.png'/> rem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <img src='https://stackoverflow.com/uploads/image2.png'/>";

// seatch and get old urls
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $old);
print_r($old);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => uploads/xyx.gif
            [1] => https://stackoverflow.com/uploads/image1.png
            [2] => https://stackoverflow.com/uploads/image2.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => uploads/xyx.gif
            [1] => https://stackoverflow.com/uploads/image1.png
            [2] => https://stackoverflow.com/uploads/image2.png
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => xyx.gif
            [1] => image1.png
            [2] => image2.png
        )

)
```

If you want to insist that image names only contain `[a-zA-Z0-9]` then change the `.*?` to `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` i.e.

```
$pattern = "#\b((?:https?://stackoverflow\.com/)?uploads/([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(?:jpg|png|gif)))\b#";
```